# How to retrieve "custom url" from image attachment in wordpress

Tags: attachments, images

I have uploaded a bunch of images to a post and set the 'custom url' for each of them in the media uploader.

How can I retrieve the custom URL assigned to each image into $caption_text= at the bottom?

```
    $images =& get_children( array( 
                            'post_parent' => $featured_page,
                            'post_status' => 'inherit',
                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'numberposts' => $thelimit,
                            'orderby' => 'menu_order' )
                            );

// Loop through the images
foreach ( $images as $id => $image ) {
    $attatchmentID = $image->ID;

    $imagearray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attatchmentID , 'fullsize', false);
    $imageURI = $imagearray[0];
    $imageID = get_post($attatchmentID);

    $thumb_imagearray = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attatchmentID , 'fullscreen-thumbnails', false);
    $thumb_imageURI = $thumb_imagearray[0];

    $imageTitle = $image->post_title;
    $imageDesc = $image->post_content;
    $postlink = get_permalink($image->post_parent);
    // If linking is On
    if ($featured_linked == 1 || $featured_linked == true) {
        $attatchmentURL = get_attachment_link($image->ID);
    }
    // Count
    $count++;
    if ($count>1) { echo ","; }

    $slideshow_title="";
    $slideshow_caption="";

    //Find and replace all new lines to BR tags
    $find   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
    $replace = '<br />';
    $imageDesc = str_replace($find, $replace , $imageDesc);
    $image_post_link = get_permalink();


    if ($imageTitle) $slideshow_title='<div class="slideshow_title">'. esc_attr($imageTitle) .'</div>';
    if ($imageDesc) $slideshow_caption='<div class="slideshow_caption">'. $imageDesc .'</div>';


    $caption_text= '<div class="slideshow_captionwrap">' . $slideshow_title . $slideshow_caption . '> <a class="slideshow_cap_link" href="' . $image_post_link . '">Preview Article</a></div>';


    echo "{image : '".$imageURI."', title : '". $caption_text . "', thumb : '".$thumb_imageURI."', url : ''}";
}
```

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using? Cause I am checking it in version 3.6 and I don't see the custom url field?

Comment: Ooops, my mistake, I didn't realize that the custom url field is only available when inserting the image to the post.  In that case, is there a way to add an extra field to each image that can store a custom URL that I can call?

Comment: Try Advanced Custom Fields, when you create a field group with it, you can choose the Attachments as a rule.

Comment: Thanks.  good idea. Found a similar solution to add fields to attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-attachments/

It's a simple plugin that adds custom fields to the attachment media editor.  You can modify the fields and then display the values within your theme.

Thanks all for the suggestions.